# ngx-translate: pipe vs directive

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have implemented [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) i18n module and got strange behaviour

```
 <span [translate]="HELLO'"></span>
```

with **directive** it works only once and does not update the text if I switch to another language, however **pipe** approach works:

```
<span >{{'HELLO'| translate}}</span>
```

Is it expected behaviour?

**UPD**: created an [issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/439) about it.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UFwOEUEdw1bqXBs3zS4w?p=preview) you could try it in plunker.

Answer (score 3):

The library [was fixed](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/commit/8753085f704665fb8dcaf003571c1dbf6db54fa4) in [v6.0.1](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/releases/tag/v6.0.1).